# Aren't comments from users who blocked you supposed to disappear from your Instagram posts?

Tags: instagram

Someone recently blocked me on Instagram. I can still see their comments on my posts. Aren't they supposed to disappear when they block you?

Comment: [What happens when you block someone on Instagram](https://help.instagram.com/447613741984126#:~:text=After%20you%20block%20someone%2C%20their,accounts%20or%20accounts%20they%20follow) They blocked you, you didn't block them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.